# Best practice to POST with optional parameters

Tags: rest, api, post

I need to define the simple request which will be posting data to the endpoint. I want to send JSON object but depending on the situation it should contain 3 or 4 fields.

#### 1 /endpoint?option=one

```
{
    "parameter1": 123,
    "parameter2": 12.2,
    "parameter3": 33.2,
    "parameter4": "test"
}
```

#### 2 /endpoint?option=two

```
{
    "parameter1": 123,
    "parameter2": 12.2,
    "parameter3": 33.2
}
```

Comment: do you need to explicitly pass "option=one" in your request? Isn't passing the list of paramers enough? what is the resource?

Comment: @Artem I know that I can but I don't know if it is a good practice

Comment: ok, let's assume we have /users endpoint. and you want to update first name only in the first post and then update date of birth in the second one (keeping first name unchanged)? is it a scenario you are asking for?

Comment: No, if I wanted to update one field I would use patch. I want to send a JSON object with dynamic number of fields. I will probably use the @Sergio answer (see below) and send null object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate the JSON and send it, in the server you check if the JSON has the field "parameter4".

If the field isn't there, then you can save it as NULL.

> EDIT

In Java you can check it like this;

```
if (jsonObject.has("parameter4")) {
    // You have the parameter
}
```

Comment: So I can just send it to one endpoint `/endpoint` and I can include either 3 or 4 fields and check if one of them is null?